# calling a Asp.net web API from c# with multiple of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web api that has parameters. I am trying to call the api from another application. This is not a problem on the client side using, but i cannot find a way to do it on the server side in c#. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call Web API from any desktop or server side application using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
webClient.Headers["X-JavaScript-User-Agent"] = "Google APIs Explorer";

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { longUrl = url });
var data = webClient.UploadString("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?pp=1", json);
```

Comment: Can you show me from the example you posted, how to send data up? like for example I have a string and a user object that I will convert to json with newtonsoft.

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2012/02/18/mvc4-and-web-api-make-an-api-the-way-you-always-wanted-part-1.aspx

The link above worked perfectly for me.